# Geolocation with cordova no result

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, telnet

I am developing an hybrid app using cordova. I'm currently working on the android app.

My **index.html** code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Narrow Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./js/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header clearfix">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="row marketing">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Subheading</h4>
                <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-succes" onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

                <p id="demo"></p>


            </div>


        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
        </footer>

        <script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
}
</script>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using following permissions in the android manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

and in the config file im using this

```
 <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
```

To fix a geolocation position on my android emulator(Android studio's) im using a telnet session with port 5554 and the geo fix 120 120 command. i get an ok back.

It used to work but then i messed up something and it stopped working until now i didn't find what i messed up and undo'ing my latest stepps didn't solve it.

when i click the button my log shows.
11-03 05:47:28.809 2079-2079/com.example.xhtml W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
11-03 05:47:28.941 2079-2079/com.example.xhtml W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
11-03 05:47:29.090 2079-2079/com.example.xhtml W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread

sometimes i also get 
11-03 05:47:16.239 2079-2096/com.example.xhtml I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15(272B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 14MB/14MB, paused 17.517ms total 37.382ms

Comment: firstly did you got success before with this code?

Comment: I did yeah. I was able to print my lat and log. and then i messed it up somewhere while adding a map. then i deleted the latest added code but somehow i deleted something that was making it work. I started a whole new project carefully doing the steps i've learned while making it the first time working but so far no succes. could it be there is some problem with memory heap or something ?

Comment: as i think there is not device ready function , hence the geolocation function needs to be called from onDeviceReady function

Comment: I want to invoke the geolocation function when i clicked the button but i'm not able to manage to do that as it seems.

Comment: ok , is this geo location standard pulgin or u created?

Comment: It seems like my deviceReady function never gets invoked...

Comment: if u need onclick of button then no need of deviceReady

Comment: yes i need it on a onclick of a button. I'm starting to think it has something to do with my emulator as i tried everything already

Comment: i just replaced `<script type="text/javascript">` in code and its working ; i hope you have added plugin properly since without changing anything in above code it should work .

Comment: No not yet... i'm wondering about these error's my browser is giving about my memory

Comment: Still haven't found the error. i copied all the code . added the plugin in all possible ways. just seems to be something messed up...

Comment: its woprking on myend , you are build into android device isnt it? or broswer?